# strsplit in R, how to change an strip

Tags: r

I have this :
mySeq <- c("GGG")

but I need to have this:
mySeq <- c("G", "G", "G")

How can I get it?

thanks in advance.

I do not know how to do it

Comment: You need `strsplit(mySeq, "")[[1]]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
library(stringr)
mySeq <- c("GGG")

unlist(str_split(string=mySeq, pattern= ""))

"G" "G" "G"
```